# How is unsigned int variable able to store negative value?

Tags: c, unsigned

When i tried the below code snippet, **its printing -1 as output**.
But how unsigned int is storing -1?

code:

```
unsigned int a = -1;
printf("a = %d \n",a)
```

The output: -1

How is this possible?

note: I saw similar question in stackoverflow. This is different. My question is why it printed -1 as output even though "a" is unsigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%d` specifier tells `printf`, "Interpret this value as a *signed* integer".  Even though `a` has a value of `0xFFFFFFFF` (4,294,967,296), when interpreted as a signed value, it will show up as -1.

Comment: Thanks for this information.